# Source Control: Multiple repositories for the same project

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, repository, commit

**Is it possible to have multiple repositories for the same project?**

I am currently using SVN with TortoiseSVN with the repositories on an external hard disk at my home, and well as regards a backup-wise solution, this isn't ideal.

So what I have in my mind is making an account with [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) and having a **second** (my home one being the first) repository to where I can commit there (even for a remote-backup solution).

Now of course, I want integrity in my code and I don't want discrepancies between the two (or more ?) repositories, which means that both repositories should be both updated when I commit my code.

So what can I do to make this happen?

Something I have in my mind is committing to my primary repository (the home one) and then it automatically commits to the online repository (the unfuddle one) **automatically** (because of course I don't want to manually commit to both repositories every time I commit my code)

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Everything's possible](http://www.codegobbler.com/mirror-svn-repository-svnsync) :)

**EDIT**: haste never leads to quality nor did my answer, missing all the Windows references in the question. So here's a run down on how to get the sync working on Windows.

You have 2 machines in this case:

- Machine A: where the repository runs
  now.
- Machine B: where you'd like to
  sync to.

Create a new repository on B that you wish to synchronise to from A. It's very important that this repository is blank (running on rev0).

On B, in the SVN folder of the newly created repository, browse to /hooks and create the following BAT files:

**start-commit.bat**

```
IF "%2" == "someusername" (goto :label1) else (echo "Only the someusername account may commit new revisions" >&2 )

exit 1
goto :eof

:label1
exit 0
```

**pre-revprop-change.bat**

```
IF "%3" == "someuser" (goto :label1) else (echo "Only the someuser user may change revision properties" >&2 )

exit 1
goto :eof

:label1
exit 0
```

`someuser` being a syncuser that exists in machine A's repository and is the only user with rights in machine B's repository. It's very important no commits are done manually to machine B's repository.

In the `/hooks` folder of the repository on machine A

**post-commit.bat**

```
CD PATH_TO_SUBVERSION\bin
svnsync sync svn://machineB/repos --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --source-username machineAusername --source-password machineApassword --sync-username machineBusername --sync-password machineBpassword
```

Once these batch files are in place we need to tell the repository on B we want to synchronise to it:

`svnsync initialize svn://`**machineB**`/repos svn://`**machineA**`/repos --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --source-username` **machineAusername** `--source-password` **machineApassword** `--sync-username` **machineBusername** `--sync-password` **machineBpassword**

which should return something like: `Copied properties for revision 0.`

Now every time you commit into the repository on machine A it will be copied over to machine B's repository.

It's very important to note that if you want to synchronise to [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code) or another online repository that they commit a trunk/branches/tags structure into revision 1. You have to contact them to reset the repository if you wish to use these third party repository location as the synchronisation repository.

To give credit where due I copied the pre-revprop-change.bat and start-commit.bat from http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=5745&sid=06551a22d9c0b5780cf1faab6b0e8ce9

I just implemented this myself on a test repository and seems to work like a charm. I'm glad I noticed this question though svnsync has sunk too deep down in my skull. I meant to do set it up when setting up svn at work. So I know what the first thing is I'll be doing at work tomorrow, thanks for that!

**EDIT 2:**

If you, like me, have tons of repositories this generic post-commit.bat might appeal to you:

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2
SET REPOS=%REPOS:D:\SVN=%

CD "C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin"

svnsync sync svn://machineB/%REPOS%-sync --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --source-username usernameA --source-password passwordA --sync-username usernameB --sync-password passwordB
```

This catches the repository name and uses it to dynamically determine the sync URL. I suffixed all my synchronisation repositories on machine B with `-sync` for clarity. The `D:\SVN` bit is the svnserve root on **machineB** even though this generic BAT file should be placed in the /hooks of **machineA**'s svnserve root.

Comment: He's using TortoiseSVN, so he's on Windows. A linux solution may not be helpful.

Comment: do forgive my hasteful reply ! i'll post up how to create your own hooks on windows.

Comment: Be prepared when syncing at a later stage when some repositories are at revision 6000 it will take a while. Found that out today when implementing syncing at work :p

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understood your problem, but I think that what you are looking for is [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnsync).

You can have your main repository inside your notebook's hard disk and a mirror repository at your desktop/home server.

Just commit your changes to the main repository and then sync it to your mirror repository(ies). This process is incremental, so only the revisions since the last sync are trasferred, but be careful with unversioned properties.

Also you might wanna take a look in [here](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt) and [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication).

Answer (score -1):

From a pure SVN perspective nope, you can only have one .svn folder which points to only 1 repo in your working folder.

You can make use of post-commit-hooks on your svn repo to try and keep both repos in  sync.. but really you just have the wrong tool if that is what you want.

The problem your are describing is at its heart a distributed version control system like GIT. Which allows you to make commits locally and also to push it to a remote repository.

You could even use GIT locally and SVN as your remote repo if you were so inclined.

- see [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) for the tool
- see [GitHub](https://github.com/) for free public hosting